# How to find out who applied a label to a version in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

In Clearcase, is there a way to find out who applied a label to a version of file? I.e. who did the mklabel. desc shows who checked in the file and the labels that are on it, but the user who did the mklabel is not necessarily the same one who did the ci. A label report shows who created the label initially. An annotated report doesn't give what I need either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could try and check [`cleartool lshistory`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%255Fref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm):

```
cleartool lshist -minor yourFile
```

That event should be recorded there.

The [event_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/events_ccase.htm) does include amongst the event tracked:

> Attach or remove an attribute, label, hyperlink, or trigger.